# how to get a property based on a parameter on a method , C#

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing

im trying to reference a field in a database table with a string parameter in my method, something like this.>>>>>

```
 public FuenteDatos methodname(string parametro)
        {

           Context db = new Context();

            var porAreas = from receptores in db.AFTs
                           where receptores.Descripcion == "anystring"
           /*this line*/   group receptores by receptores.Receptor.[parametro] into tablanueva




//from this point is irrelevant

}
```

so, if  parametro = "area", the

```
var = var porAreas = from receptores in db.AFTs
                       where receptores.Descripcion == "anystring"
       /*this line*/   group receptores by receptores.Receptor.area into tablanueva
```

my question, what is the syntaxis to do this'?_

Comment: Usually you just pass it as parameter (like `methodname(receptores=>receptores.Receptor.area)`... Why doesn't it work for you? Do you expect string and need to build expression tree manually?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov im specting the string from a user input, so , i have to do it that way, if the user enters "Computers", then var porAreas = .... by receptores.Receptor.Computers....

Comment: It sounds like you want an expression tree, but I am also not 100% the true problem you are trying to solve... a dynamic group by expression in this example?

Comment: Doing so is a bad practice, because the text must match your object properties exactly. Give him options and build an expression yourself instead of feeding user input directly.

Comment: The whole point of using LINQ like this is for statically defined queries.  If you're going to be dynamically determining your schema like this, just use a traditional SQL query.

Comment: You're describing how you think the solution would look like. What is the *actual* question? How to group dynamically? You can already pass any property you want in code. You can also use the method syntax to make different `.GroupBy(...)` calls, eg `if (someFlag) { query=query.GroupBy(x=>x.ThisProperty);}`. Or you can use a switch statement or expression to select different lambdas to pass to `GroupBy`

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to create a generic query generator from eg a filter form, like those found in commercial grids, you need to either build an expression tree or use reflection to create the lambdas on the fly. Most of the time, schemas change so rarely it's far less trouble to write an extra `if` or `case` than it is to write a well behaving query generator

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want conditional operator:

```
var sql1 = from receptores in db.AFTs
           where receptores.Descripcion == "anystring"
           group receptores by receptores.Receptor.[parametro] into tablanueva;
var sql2 = from receptores in db.AFTs
           where receptores.Descripcion == "anystring"
           group receptores by receptores.Receptor.area into tablanueva;
var porAreas = parametro == "area" ? sql2 : sql1;
```

Comment: Give me an up to this answer, I am appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If all of the properties of `Receptor` that you want to `GroupBy` are of a single type then this becomes relatively easy. If the types change, then it's a bit more problematic, but it can be done.

Here's the version assuming all are strings. I've had to assume type names because you didn't provide a [mcve].

I've made up this type:

```
public class Receptor
{
    public string Descripcion;
    public string Apple;
    public string Banana;
}
```

Your query is essentially this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Aft>> porAreas =
    db.AFTs.AsQueryable()
        .Where(receptores => receptores.Descripcion == "anystring")
        .GroupBy(receptores => receptores.Receptor.Apple);
```

You can parameterize this by first creating a dictionary of the expressions:

```
private Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Aft, string>>> _maps =
    new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Aft, string>>>()
    {
        { "apple", receptores => receptores.Receptor.Apple },
        { "banana", receptores => receptores.Receptor.Banana },
    };
```

Now you can call your query like this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Aft>> porAreas =
    db.AFTs.AsQueryable()
        .Where(receptores => receptores.Descripcion == "anystring")
        .GroupBy(_maps["Apple"]);
```

That should be fairly simple to follow.

Let me know if you need the more complicated, multi-type solution.